# Как задать цвет половине border?

Tags: javascript, html, css, tailwindcss

Столкнулся с формой , в которой при правильном заполнении формы (valid) нижний border должен покраситься на половину в зелёный. Как это сделать в css или js?

Comment: А что уже имеется? А какие знания по js уже есть у вас? На какой уровень рассчитывать?

Comment: border-image в помощь. либо имитировать эффект border

Comment: А что сразу минус бал ставить, интересный же вопрос

Comment: Вопрос, на мой взгляд имеет право на существование. Поэтому его, хорошо бы переоткрыть. Вопрос поставили на закрытие, как я предполагаю из-за слова "border" Особо не вчитываясь в условия, что показывают ответы. А вопрос на самом деле интересный.

Comment: @Alexandr_TT, просто это составной вопрос, в котором даже я, ничего не смыслящий во всех этих css-ах/javascript-ах, ясно вижу как минимум три подвопроса. ну, и, как обычно, напомню вам лично: чтобы вопрос остался, он вовсе необязательно должен быть открыт.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin Если вопрос останется закрытым, то получение новых ответов теоретически невозможно. Существующие ответы не вполне точно отвечают. И вам лично, тоже могу повторить,- при желании можно придраться к любому телеграфному столбу и по этому принципу можно закрыть 50% всех вопросов про frontend'y

Comment: @Alexandr_TT `Существующие ответы не вполне точно отвечают` — и это вполне нормально: на составной вопрос очень трудно дать **один** исчерпывающий ответ. гораздо лучше для составных вопросов будет дать ссылки на уже существующие более элементарные вопросы, из которых он состоит. // думаю, вам, как специалисту в данной области, это не составит большого труда. таким образом вы поможете всем, кто из поисковиков наткнётся на данный составной вопрос: справа в списке связанных он увидит всё, что ему будет необходимо.

Comment: @Alexandr_TT согласен

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin благодарю за положительный отзыв. Но я всё же приверженец, того, что решать, нужен или не нужен вопрос должны всё таки люди, которые разбираются в данной специализации. А не принимать решение по каким-то формальным признакам. Могу привести пример, когда я был вынужден написать статью на мете, когда настойчиво предлагали разбить вопрос на несколько отдельных подвопросов -  [Нужно ли анимацию объекта делить на несколько простыx составляющиx анимаций?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/11209/28748)

Comment: @Alexandr_TT, ну и, кстати, по поводу тематики, которую вы назвали «frontend». я так предполагаю, это речь про языки css/html/javascript. мне думается, что в этих языках нет ничего особенного, что как-то качественно отличало бы вопросы, заданные относительно этих языков: новички (да и не только новички) на **любом** языке программирования/разметки/ещё-чего-нибудь стараются вывалить стояющую перед ними проблему целиком, очень редко пытаясь сначала эту проблему разбить на какие-то составные части.

Comment: @Alexandr_TT `решать, нужен или не нужен вопрос должны всё таки люди, которые разбираются в данной специализации` — несомненно. а вот проголосовать за закрытие явно составного вопроса (напомню ещё раз: за закрытие, а не за удаление) может и любой здравомыслящий человек. // ну и по поводу данного вопроса разрешите привести мнение одного из здравомыслящих людей: несомненно, данный вопрос нужен (закрытый или открытый): кто-нибудь наверняка наткнётся на него в поисках ответа на что-то похожее. и вот таким новичкам **очень** пригодится список ссылок на более элементарные вопросы.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin  Вы прошли по моей ссылке, хоть бегло прочитали? Насчет составных вопросов? Знаете, я прекрасно понимаю вас. Качество вопросов упало сильно ниже плинтуса, просто безобразие. Но в каждом конкретном случае нужно разбираться конкретно. Тот, предыдущий вопрос, где мы спорили, действительно был ценный и получил развитие в новых вопросах.

Comment: @Alexandr_TT, да, я прочитал по поводу предложения разбивать на под-вопросы вопросы про рисование. это уже черезчур далеко от моей области интересов. // ну а по поводу данного вопроса: мне кажется, наибольший интерес вызвал тот под-вопрос, который вынесен в заголовок. так напишите его отдельно, и дайте хороший ответ (наверняка там и несколько вариантов можно привести). а здесь приведите на него ссылку. по-моему, так будет просто замечательно.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin и тут же найдется человек, который объявит вопрос дублем :) Это же удобно так и ссылка будет Я бы мог переоформить грамотно вопрос, так как прекрасно понимаю, что хочет автор, но помните какие были войны откатов и обвинения в мой адрес в вандализме вопроса.

Comment: @Alexandr_TT, да, воевать не стоит, даже с помощью правок. а «дубли», похоже, вам не нравятся. и зря — они помогают связывать схожие вопросы. даже если больше никто за дубликат и не проголосует — ссылка будет в списке связанных вопросов. собственно, того же эффекта связности можно добиться и простым упоминанием ссылки в ответе, комментарии и даже в самом вопросе. // а связность информации — это просто бальзам для базы знаний.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin  `связность информации — это просто бальзам для базы знаний` не спорю, когда это используется по назначению. Но ведь бывает чаще такое, когда дублем объявляется вопрос со **ссылкой на свой вопрос** для привлечения внимания, хотя объявленный дубликатом-вопрос и не является дублем по большому счету. Объявляется вопрос дублем, опять же по набору формальных признаков, похожести заголовков. И как результат,- вопрос закрытый дублем не может получить новых ответов. А новые ответы по ссылке на первоисточник дубля, там совсем будут не к месту

Answer (score 2):

Самый правильный способ:

1. Задать какой-то класс в *CSS*
2. При валидации через *JS* либо добавлять этот самый класс, либо удалять

Пример CSS может быть такой:

```css
div.test {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: white;
}

div.test::before {
    position: absolute;
    content: '';
    width: 104px;
    height: 107px;
    top: 4px;
    background: linear-gradient(to left, #dd0a0a, #2e76a9);
    z-index: -1;    
    left: 4px;
}
```

```html
<div class=test>test</div>
```

Comment: утонченная изощренность, сначала ответить на вопрос, а потом отдать голос на закрытие. Ну если это ради медальки - "Ревизор", то теперь есть возможность отдать голос на переоткрытие

Comment: @Alexandr_TT всё было наоборот, вначале голос за закрытие, потом ответ) Просто вспомнил, что бордер сам недавно делал такой (если я правильно понял какой нужно). С закрытием на самом деле забыл, что я голосовал, ну бывает. Думаю его всё равно закрыли бы.

Comment: **нижний border должен покраситься на половину в зелёный.** если я правильно понял, то закрасить нижнюю половину, а не удалить половину

Answer (score 2):

Вот что я придумал, надеюсь помог вам

```js
const form = document.getElementById("form-test");
const inputForm = form.getElementsByTagName("input");

for (let i = 0; i < inputForm.length; i++) {
  inputForm[i].addEventListener("keyup", function() {
    let num = 0;
    for (let j = 0; j < inputForm.length; j++) {
      if (inputForm[j].value.length != 0) num++;
    }
    
    if (num >= (inputForm.length / 2)) form.classList.add("border");
    else form.classList.remove("border");
    
    if(num == inputForm.length) form.classList.add("border-full");
    else form.classList.remove("border-full");
  });
}
```

```css
.form {
  width: 80%;
  height: 250px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  position: relative;
}

.form div {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 50%;
}

.form div label {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.form:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  width: 0;
  height: 4px;
  background-color: green;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  transition: .5s;
}

.border:after{
  width: 50%;
}

.border-full:after{
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<form class="form" id="form-test">
  <div>
    <label for="firstname">Имя</label>
    <input type="text" id="firstname">
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="lastname">Фамилия</label>
    <input type="text" id="lastname">
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="email">Почта</label>
    <input type="email" id="email">
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="age">Возраст</label>
    <input type="number" id="age">
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="password">Пароль</label>
    <input type="text" id="password">
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="confirm-password">Повторите пароль</label>
    <input type="text" id="confirm-password">
  </div>
  <input type="submit" value="Отправить">
</form>
```

Comment: можешь проголосовать за переоткрытие. Свой ответ подправь немного,- **нижний border должен покраситься на половину в зелёный**

Comment: @Alexandr_TT знал бы я как)

Comment: @Alexandr_TT да не вижу T-T, но надеюсь переоткроют